# Chatbot - How can I send emoji in messenger chatbot

Tags: facebook, laravel, api, chatbot, messenger

- I'm doing chatbot based on Giga AI Messenger bot, and I have problem when bot automatic reply, it can not send emoji.
- I set  charset encoding is utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_general_ci in both database connection (in database.php) and in database schema (I use navicat).
- In original Giga AI, when I save reply with emoji to database, I can see emoji when use PhpMyadmin, but with navicat, it show "?" for that emoji like `[{"text":"?"}]`
  But when I save with json_encode(), it show unicode string like  `[{"text":"\"\\ud83d\\ude02\""}]`.
- So how can I send emoji from bot to messenger?
  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Make sure your DB support UTF8mb4 AND your wp-config.php file DB_CHARSET is utf8mb4 instead of utf8. This is WP config problem, not GigaAI.

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Yeah, I did. GigaAI use themselve configuration. I must edit in vendor ( Storage.php)

Comment: @RolandJohansson I resolved it, thanks